# Изменение компилятора С++ VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc

Раньше я использовал Visual Studio для своих проектов на C++. Но я решил перейти на VS Code и установить GCC компилятор. Я скачал MinGw, установил, добавл в путь. С помощью расширения C++ через UI настроил MinGw. Но каждый раз при перезапуске компьютера у меня компилятор автоматически меняется на тот, что в Visual Studio.

[image: скриншот]

> [11.03.2021, 00:25:25] Для исходных файлов C++ cppStandard был изменен с "gnu++20" на "c++20" на основе аргументов компилятора и compilerPath запроса: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

Как можно исправить эту проблему и что посоветуете?

Comment: При перезагрузке компа или при перезапуске VS Code? Что если закрыть его до перезагрузки компа? И зачем вообще в этой схеме расширение?

Comment: @qwertiy при перезагрузке компа, vs code закрываю. Расширение для IntelliSense

Comment: Но ты же про настройку компилятора говоришь. Что всё-таки не работает - компиляция или подсветка?

Comment: @qwertiy проблема в том, что при перезагрузке компа автоматически менятся компилятор и мне приходится каждый раз менять его на MinGw